# Why is 'babel-register' giving an exception in unit tests?

Tags: npm, mocha.js

I am a bit frustrated... I have been attempting to get babel-register on the path for a unit test, but over and over... it *does not* seem to show up when running mocha. Is there something we are missing?

In particular, I have a package.json that includes babel-register, and I do an install based on this package. However, when I attempt to run mocha, I keep getting the error that the package isn't found. Any recommendations?

Here is the exact errors if that will help debug:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<Path to test which is failing>\<test>.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

This is after I have already tried installing babel-register globally, in the hope it would fix it.